# Docker-compose, migration with evolve on a mariadb

Tags: docker-compose, migration, evolve

I'm attempting to use evolve migration for my db, in docker-compose, enabling a local version of production for development. The idea is for each time I start my docker-compose, the changes to my db tables will be migrated. I started using docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, but this requires a full restart of the db to enact the table changes, which would lead to a loss of all the db data in my volume, which I want to have persistent data.

In my docker-compose file I have the following, migrate indicates the migration, the out commented line in the database, is what I used before attempting migration:

```
version: '3.4'
name: dockertest
services:
  dockertestapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockertestapi
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: DockerTestApi/Dockerfile
    container_name: DockerTest-service
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=LocalDocker
    ports:
      - 5237:80
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
      - ./rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
    healthcheck:
        test: rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.9 
    container_name: database
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
        #- ../Migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ../../dockertest-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dockertestdb
  migrate: 
    image: <base_url>/backend/evolve-bin:master 
    command: evolve migrate mariadb -c "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=dockertestdb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" -l "/tmp/migrations" 
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
        - ../Migrations:/tmp/migrations
volumes:
  dockertest-data:
networks:
  backend:
```

I have removed the url and replaced it with base_url, for the purpose of this question.
Everything is working and spinning up nicely in docker, except the migrate, which gives the following error:

> Unrecognized command or argument 'mariadb'

Note: I need to use mariadb and evolve for the migration to replicate what is used in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, I needed to add migrate to the network backend, remove evolve from the command and change the server from localhost to database referencing the database container.

Here is the full yaml:

```
version: '3.4'
name: dockertest
services:
  dockertestapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockertestapi
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: DockerTestApi/Dockerfile
    container_name: DockerTest-service
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=LocalDocker
    ports:
      - 5237:80
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - "./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"
      - "./rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
    healthcheck:
        test: rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.9 
    container_name: database
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
        - ../../dockertest-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dockertestdb
    healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 20s
            retries: 10
  migrate: 
    image: <base_url>/backend/evolve-bin:master 
    container_name: migrate
    command: migrate mariadb -c "Server=database;Port=3306;Database=dockertestdb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" -l "/tmp/migrations" 
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
        - ../Migrations:/tmp/migrations    
volumes:
  dockertest-data:
networks:
  backend:
```